# Enthalpy of formation at other temperatures

Tags: thermodynamics

I was told each compound has an enthalpy of formation of 0 at the standard temperature if it is in it's lowest energy modification. But what if we change the temperature? It would make sense to me that we would also need to have a non-zero enthalpy of formation then, like for Hydrogen at 400K. Is that the case? Many exercises I had to calculate $ \Delta H_r$ in had no enthalpies of formation given for $H_2$, even if all compounds were at 400K.

Comment: The enthalpy of formation of each compound is equal to the enthalpy change from the elements in their natural states at the temperature under consideration.  If you work it out, this will enable you to get heats of reactions at the temperature without correcting for the sensible heat changes of the elements relative to the standard temperature.

Comment: What do you mean by "each compound"? Maybe you mean "each element"?